# How to limit the number of MDI tab groups

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created a MDI application with [tabbed group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165830.aspx).

Each time I drag and drop one tab from tab bar to view, it will create a new tab group and divide view according to the number of tab groups. But I want to allow my application to create only two tab groups.

I have done my work by regrouping a new tab group with the tab group related to the drag-and-drop tab.

But this solution is not good because the view blinks for a short time.

I'm looking for a better solution. I know: drag-and-drop tab to view => create new tab group is default support by MDI Tabbed Group.

How do I check it and prevent it?

Comment: Have any one can help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete job of detaching and moving the Tabs arround is done upon the message AFX_WM_ON_MOVETABCOMPLETE (registered Windows message), this message is handled by CMDIClientAreaWnd::OnMoveTabComplete.

So you can subclass your MDI client window and you can intercept the message.
Check what you want, and if you don't want to allow the drag&drop Operation just return.

If you want to allow this drag&drop just call the base implementation CMDIClientAreaWnd::OnMoveTabComplete.

Comment: Thanks so much for your respond. But could you explain more: How to intercept that message? Need I create my MDI client window to use ínstead of default CMDIClientAreaWnd. I don't know how to do that because I see MDI client is use by system class CMDIFrameWndEx.

Comment: AFAIK the Client window is create din a Frame function named CreateClient. Derive our own class and create a handler for that message.

Comment: CMainFrame in my app is inherited CMDIFrameWndEx, and CMDIFrameWndEx subclases default MDI client window itself. So I can't subclass other MDI client window :(. http://silviuardelean.ro/2012/10/21/subclasswindow-method-issues-in-projects-base-on-mfc-feature-pack-2/                                                                     Is there another way to intercept that message ?.

Comment: You may just use "classic subclassing"