# Client Area CMDIFrameWndEx

Tags: c++, mfc

Good afternoon!
I'm updating my application from CMDIFrameWnd to CMDIFrameWndEx, and faced with the problem of client area of MainFrame.Before I had m_hWndMDIClient, and Subclass to it with my class. Now I have m_wndClientArea, and it brings me only headache! Now I can't Subclass. That's why I tried to do this:

```
mdiCliWnd_.Attach(m_wndClientArea.Detach());
mdiCliWnd_.Invalidate();
mdiCliWnd_.UpdateWindow();
m_wndClientArea.Attach(mdiCliWnd_.Detach());
```

But I can't even check how it work,because now I have a problem, that I should give CWnd of my client area to another functions, but  m_wndClientArea is protected. 
So my questions are : Can I subclass my own class in another way? If I can't, how I should use  m_wndClientArea to give it to another functions?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for that subclassing?

If it is just about drawing the background, use the new virtual function:
OnEraseMDIClientArea

Otherwise it is no problem to use the standard subclassing.

Because the HWND handle of the mdi client window is already attached to a MFC CWnd class object you can't use the MFC subclassing again.

Comment: The main reason is to use OnRButtonUp (etc) functions in client area! 
I read your answer about "classical subclassing" here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209469/how-to-limit-the-number-of-mdi-tab-groups , but I don't understand ,what particulary I should subclass - CMDIClientAreaWnd or CMDIFrameWndEx and how?

Comment: You subclass a handle not an object! m_hWndMDIClient. What is the reason for detecting RButtonUP/Down? Context menus should be implements with WM_CONTEXTMENU and this messages is passed on to the parent windows...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to standatd subclass a handle.. As I undestand - SubclassWindow(pParentFrm_->m_hWndMDIClient) - is MFC subclassing, because it gives me error of already subclass object. So can you give me please example of  "standatd subclass a handle"

Comment: Just google. First link https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: So, as I understand from the link I can subclass only procedure, but not class, am I wright?

Comment: You always subclass one window. And yes even if you subclass the window procedure you change the behaviour of the class.